# What does .foo : { *(.*) } mean in a linker script?

Tags: assembly, linker-scripts

I'm writing a bootable program that is 512 bytes, and I have to stick the 0xAA55 in the last 2 bytes of my 512 byte program image.  So I've done that.  Now my linker script, should be pretty simple.  I was just curious about what this syntax means

```
.foo : { *(.*) }
```

I was given it as an example.  There is no .foo section, and before that, I change the program counter to

```
. = 0x1000 //To account for the elf header which I will strip later
```

So after this directive is

```
.foo : { *(.*) }
```

What does this do?

Comment: I have never worked with linker scripts, but two minutes of Googling found [this documentation on "linker script wildcards"](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html), which suggests that that line instructs the linker to combine all the sections into one, named `.foo`.

Answer (score 2):

It stores in section `.foo` all code, data, bss, rodata, etcetera (the second `*`) from all object files (the first `*`) that aren't yet assigned to any previously defined section.